# SQLServerAgent Error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, errors

I have created the following as an automated job to run at midnight on every database server I manage:

[image: Automated Log Cycle Job]

This job fails intermittently on some servers, but not others and I get the following error:

> SQL Agent - Jobs Failed: The SQL Agent Job
>   "ucjSQLerrorLogNightlyCycle" failed at Wednesday, November 22, 2017
>   12:00:00 AM with the error "The job failed. The Job was invoked by
>   Schedule 9 (NightlySQLError). The last step to run was step 1
>   (SQLErrorLogCycle). - Executed as user: MyDomain\MyServiceAccount. SQLServerAgent
>   Error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by
>   another process. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22022). NOTE: The step was
>   retried the requested number of times (3) without succeeding. The step
>   failed."

I receive the following error when I execute `EXEC dbo.sp_cycle_agent_errorlog;` in the query analyzer (which wasn't happening before):

> Msg 22022, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 SQLServerAgent Error: The process
>   cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I have performed an intensive search on this error message and have not found much of anything.  The only gem I found was to use Process Explorer from the SysInternals suite by Mark Russinovich.  However, isolating the SQLAgent.exe binary did not show me what other process is using it; the process is lone.  I am either performing the incorrect steps or my process is completely wrong.

Other items to note:

- I have verified that another process isn't running at the same time
- I have ran the job in the middle of the day on a weekend and it will keep running until it fails
- I can copy and paste the code into the SSMS or Toad and the code will execute as expected
- I submitted a ticket to my Infrastructure department to make sure there is an exclusion in the antivirus log folder that SQL Server Agent manipulates.
- I disabled the antivirus and performed the same aforementioned steps with the same result
- Broke the job down into two different steps as Aaron suggested.  The code `EXEC sp_cycle_errorlog;` works inside of a job and in the query analyzer.  The code `EXEC dbo.sp_cycle_agent_errorlog;` does **NOT** work in a job **OR** in the query analyzer.
- Added the path of the SQL Server Agent log file path to the list of exclusions in our antivirus and it did not solve the problem.
- Restarting the SQL Server Agent allowed me to run the job successfully, but I don't consider this a "**fix**"

Comment: The job itself is trying to modify a file that is in use.  Can you post the t-sql for ucjSQLerrorLogNightlyCycle?

Comment: The code is in the screenshot I provided.

Comment: Try separating the two operations into two distinct steps, then you can at least narrow down whether it's the agent log or the SQL Server error log that's failing (and to see if it *might* be failing on both, you could set the first step to move to the second step on success or failure).

Comment: On the server that it fails on, is there anti virus software running or another program outside of MSSQL that could be locking the log files?

Comment: I updated the information in the OP based on questions and input.  Also, I'm waiting on the system to propagate the change Infrastructure performed with the AV exclusion.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, it shows up on one (and only one) of my servers every couple of months or so.  I have been unable to determine what is causing it, but if you restart the SQL Server Agent it will go away for a while.

Comment: Most likely the SQL Agent service has locked the log file. For fun on a test system where this is a problem (if you have one) shut the agent service off then try cycling the agent error log.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up on this matter.  The antivirus exclusion made no difference, the problem still exists.  However, restarting the SQL Server Agent service allowed the job to complete successfully.  I don't consider this the answer as the issue will come back again.  I would like to know why and how this issue is caused, especially since it perplexes so many folks.  I found a M$ connect item on this, but it doesn't seem to be solved.  In addition, I added more info to the OP based on more input and troubleshooting for easier reference in the future.